# If else logic for single column in data frame then apply to all columns

Tags: r

How can I make in data frame if certain condition applies to a single column then all rows for that data frame will be Null.

For example I had a data frame.

```
A<- c(2,3,5,6,5,7,8,5)
B <- c("AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "HI", "IJ")
C <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "W")
ABC <-data.frame(A,B,C)
> ABC
  A  B C
1 2 AB X
2 3 BC Y
3 5 CD Z
4 6 DE W
5 5 EF X
6 7 FG Y
7 8 HI Z
8 5 IJ W
```

And I want for every `ABC$A` equals to 5, then all rows connects with 5 will be NULL or NA.

My desired output should look like this

```
> ABC
  A    B    C
1 2   AB    X
2 3   BC    Y
3 5 <NA> <NA>
4 6   DE    W
5 5 <NA> <NA>
6 7   FG    Y
7 8   HI    Z
8 5 <NA> <NA>
```

`ifelse` function could make this work but what if I had a lot of columns. And I want it to apply to all columns besides `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use row/column subsetting and assign `NA`s to all columns directly.

```
ABC[ABC$A == 5, -1] <- NA

ABC
#  A    B    C
#1 2   AB    X
#2 3   BC    Y
#3 5 <NA> <NA>
#4 6   DE    W
#5 5 <NA> <NA>
#6 7   FG    Y
#7 8   HI    Z
#8 5 <NA> <NA>
```

Here `-1` is to ignore first column `A` since we do not want to change any values in that column.

---

Some other variations

```
ABC[-1] <- lapply(ABC[-1], function(x) replace(x, ABC$A == 5, NA))
```

and using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
ABC %>%  mutate_at(-1, ~replace(., A == 5, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks, If I set "-2" it will ignore the first 2 columns?

Comment: @Mr.Buster No, with -2 it will ignore only 2nd column. You need `ABC[, -(1:2)]` to ignore first 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
ABC %>%
     mutate_at(-1, list(~ na_if(A, y = 5)))
```